# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x) = \sin(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2})$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that  $f_n(x) = \sin(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2})$, $x\in [0,\infty)$ converges point wise to $0$.

Clearly $f_n(0) \rightarrow 0$ so suppose $x\neq 0$.

I constructed a right triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}$ and sides $\sqrt{x}$ (horizontal) and $2\pi n$ (vertical). If $\theta$ is the angle between the hypotenuse and the horizontal leg ($\sqrt{x}$) in the triangle, then 
$$\theta = \arctan\frac{2\pi n}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Now, from the triangle again we get that $$\sin{\theta} = \frac{2\pi n}{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}} $$
Meaning that $$\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2} = \frac{2\pi n}{\sin{\theta}}=\frac{2\pi n}{\sin\bigg({\arctan\frac{2\pi n }{\sqrt{x}}}\bigg)}\equiv \alpha$$

Note here that $n\rightarrow \infty$ gives $\sin\bigg({\arctan\frac{2\pi n }{\sqrt{x}}}\bigg) = 1$

Penultimately,

$$\sin{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}} = \sin(\alpha)$$
For large $n$, $\sin(\alpha)$ is close to $\sin(2\pi n) = 0$ and so we are done.

**I would like to ask if this approach makes sense and if there is an easier way to get the answer that I am just not seeing. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use
$$\sqrt{x+4\pi^2 n^2}=2\pi n+\frac{x}{2\pi n+\sqrt{x+4\pi^2 n^2}}$$